# Python - Row is not aligned with column when printing dictionary in a table column fashion

Tags: python

The 2 first rows are aligned perfectly with the columns and right justified. But the 3rd one is not. This is because the word "Fib Memory" is shorter than "Fib Iteration" and "Fib Recursion". Any ideas on how I can fix this?

**Output:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
             DURATION FOR EACH APPROACH WITHIN INTERVAL: 30-0              

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                 Seconds     Milliseconds      Microseconds      Nanoseconds       
Fib Iteration    0.00100          1.00064            1000.6          1000642       
Fib Recursion    0.82556        825.56272          825562.7        825562715       
Fib Memory   0.00100          1.00040            1000.4          1000404
```

Note that the 3rd row (Fib Memory) is not aligned with the duration headers..

**Code:**

Function to convert number into string. Switcher is dictionary type here. This is a function to proper format for duration.

```
def duration_format(duration: float, precision: str) -> str:
    switcher = {
        'Seconds': "{:.5f}".format(duration),
        'Milliseconds': "{:.5f}".format(duration * 1_000),
        'Microseconds': "{:.1f}".format(duration * 1_000_000),
        'Nanoseconds': "{:d}".format(int(duration * 1_000_000_000))
    }

    return switcher.get(precision, "nothing")
```

Function which handles printing to console:

```
def print_statistics(fib_details: dict, nth_value: int):
    print(LINE)
    print("{:^75}".format("DURATION FOR EACH APPROACH WITHIN INTERVAL: " + str(nth_value) + "-0"))
    print(LINE)
    print("{0}\t\t\t\t {1:<11} {2:<17} {3:<17} {4:<18}".format("", "Seconds", "Milliseconds", "Microseconds",
                                                               "Nanoseconds"))
    for function in fib_details:
        print("{0}\t {1:<11} {2:<17} {3:<17} {4:<18}".format(
            function.split(" ")[0].capitalize() + " " + function.split(" ")[1].capitalize(),
            duration_format(fib_details[function][0], "Seconds"),
            str(duration_format(fib_details[function][0], "Milliseconds")).rjust(12),
            duration_format(fib_details[function][0], "Microseconds").rjust(12),
            duration_format(fib_details[function][0], "Nanoseconds").rjust(11)))
```

This the the dictionary:

```
fib_details = {  # store measurement information in a dictionary
        'fib iteration': fibonacci_iterative(nth_value),
        'fib recursion': fibonacci_recursive(nth_value),
        'fib memory': fibonacci_memory(nth_value)
    }
```

Comment: Print column one with a specified width (at the moment the format is {0} which is as wide as the string printed), and truncate the string to that width.

Comment: Changed it to {0:<12} and it worked, thanks for the tip!